# Python - Search a list of strings from a text file in a large .csv file

Tags: python, string, search, design-patterns, grep

Apologies, as I am probably making a whole host of errors here, but I am trying to search with a list of strings from a file (justgenes.txt) against a large CSV file and return the lines featuring the strings from the justgenes list.

I've been working largely with BASH, but the code I have takes more than 100GB of memory and crashes:

```
grep -f justgenes.txt allDandHunique.csv > HPCgenesandbugs.csv
```

Therefore, I am attempting to do it in python, assuming that it will be more efficient, but I have very little knowledge of it.

I use this code (which I've grabbed from the web), but getting an empty file at the end:

```
data = open('allDandHunique.csv')
                
with open('justgenes.txt', "r+") as file1:
    fileline1= file1.readlines()
    for x in data: # <--- Loop through the list to check      
        for line in fileline1: # <--- Loop through each line
            if x in line:
                 print(x)
```

The justgenes file looks like this:

```
1A0N_B
1A1A_A
1A4I_A
1A5Y_A
1ACO_A
1AGN_A
1AGS_A
1AJE_A
1AJJ_A
1AP0_A
1APQ_A
```

whilst the csv looks like this:

```
"0403181A:PDB=1BP2,2BPP",
"0403181A:PDB=1BP2,2BPP",,,
"0706243A:PDB=1HOE,2AIT,3AIT,4AIT",
"0706243A:PDB=1HOE,2AIT,3AIT,4AIT",,,
"1309311A:PDB=1EMD,2CMD",
"1309311A:PDB=1EMD,2CMD",,,
"1513188A:PDB=1BBC,1POD",
"1513188A:PDB=1BBC,1POD",,,
0308206A,
0308206A,,,
0308221A,
0308221A,,,
0308230A,
0308230A,,,
```

Any help would be gratefully received.

Comment: I was hoping to search all columns in the csv

Comment: Ok give me a minute

Comment: It would help if you added an example of a matching line, and what you want to output. How big is your justgenes.txt? How big is your allDandHunique.csv? Do you want to match the line when one of the strings (e.g. 1A1A_A) exactly matches a column or could it be a substring of a column? And do you want to output the whole row if there is a match, or just some part of the row?

Comment: So, I want any line containing the whole string (e.g. 1A1A_A) anywhere on the line. The output should be each and every (entire) line containing the strings from the list. The output examples would be "1513188A:PDB=1BBC,1A1A_A", which I know isn't visible in the example data. The justgenes.txt file is 1,866,642 lines and the allDandHunique.csv has 5,610,939 lines.

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas to accomplish this.

Try something like:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('allDandHunique.csv')

with open('justgenes.txt', "r+") as file1:
    fileline1= file1.readlines()
    for x in fileline1: 
      for col in df:
         if col.str.contains(x, regex=False):
             ##do something here##
```

If when reading the file in you are getting a blank file, I would check and make sure the path is correct.

Comment: Then my comment no longer applies ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have the files, I couldn't test it myself but I assume this code might help.

```
data = open('allDandHunique.csv')
        
for x in data: # <--- Loop through the list to check      
    with open('justgenes.txt', "r+") as file1:
        fileline1= file1.readlines()
        for line in fileline1: # <--- Loop through each line
            if x in line:
                    print(x)
```

For each `x in data` you have to loop over all lines in file1. If I'm not wrong, you need to open your file for each iteration, otherwise, when you reach EOF it returns nothing then.

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('justGenes') as infile:
    searchTargets = set(line.strip() for line in infile)


with open('allDandHunique.csv') as infile:
    for row in csv.reader(infile):
        if any(target in row for target in searchTargets):
            print(row)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.